# Submit multiple items on a Drop Off Library - SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, drag-and-drop, submit, drop-off-library

I'm trying to use SPO content organizer to make life easier for the end user (or DOL [Drop Off Library from now on]), the idea is that they don't have to mind about where they upload the documents, simply that the documents are being uploaded and routed according to the requirements. This is awesome in theory, as long as they upload file by file using the web upload option, something that I hate and if I propose, all the efforts and work put in place to increase adoption would quickly drop.

I've trained users to upload multiple files and use Quick Edit to add any metadata they use and require, so I would like to use this option with the DOL. The problem is that if they do this, the documents just sit there until a timer is triggered (Once every 24 hours). If I tell them to wait a whole day for it to happen, the awesomeness of it will turn into ire.

My question:

- Is there a way to "Submit" multiple files at once for the DOL to route the items without waiting for the 24h trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Support confirmed there is no way out of the box to do this. The only way would be that after doing the Quick Edit to input the metadata, someone would have to manually go to the item properties and hit Submit, which is definitely not the ideal way, yet with training this could be done rather quickly.